# Code to initialize, set, or get node properties

Tags: javascript, comparative-review

I have this JavaScript excerpt, and I was wondering if this (primarily the usage of switch case) would be considered good practice. One item of note is that I have it separated into two similar parts to not evaluate the same boolean check over and over again when it is static the whole time.

```
if (strict) {
  for (var i = 0, len = node.properties.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var other = node.properties[i];
    if (other.key.name !== prop.key.name) continue;
    var otherKind = other.kind;
    switch (kind) { // used as a kind of goto
    case "init":
    case "get":
    case "set":
      if (otherKind === "get" ||
          otherKind === "set" ||
          otherKind === "init")
        raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
  }
} else if (sawGetSet)) {
  loop:
  for (var i = 0, len = node.properties.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var other = node.properties[i];
    if (other.key.name !== prop.key.name) continue;
    var otherKind = other.kind;
    switch (kind) { // used as a kind of goto
    case "get":
    case "set":
      if (otherKind === "init") break;
    case "init":
      if (otherKind === "get" || otherKind === "set") break;

    default: continue loop; // skip the below portion, don't throw error
    }
    raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
  }
}
```

Should I rewrite it like this, something else, or leave it as is? (Speed still is important.)

```
if (strict) {
  for (var i = 0, len = node.properties.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var other = node.properties[i];
    if (other.key.name !== prop.key.name) continue;
    var otherKind = other.kind;
    if ((kind === "init" ||
         kind === "get" ||
         kind === "set") &&
        (otherKind === "get" ||
         otherKind === "set" ||
         otherKind === "init")) {
      raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
    }
  }
} else if (sawGetSet)) {
  for (var i = 0, len = node.properties.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var other = node.properties[i];
    if (other.key.name === prop.key.name) continue;
    var otherKind = other.kind;
    if ((kind === "get" ||
         kind === "set") &&
        (otherKind === "init" ||
         otherKind === "get" ||
         otherKind === "set")) {
      raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
    } else if ((kind === "init") &&
               (otherKind === "get" ||
                otherKind === "set")) {
      raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back your recent edits. Even though the edit did not massively change your initial code (it did fix one bug though), it *did* make the current answer seem incomplete. Please consider putting the new code as a new question. We have a [meta question that covers these situations](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

Answer (score 6):

For one, I'm wondering about `strict` vs `sawGetSet`, and why it's an `if...else if` structure (instead of just using one of the two variables, and an `if...else`). But without knowing the rest of the code, I won't get into that.

Anyway, I see no need for `switch` statements. I don't know if I'd call it "bad practice", but it is certainly *strange practice* to use a `switch` when it's not really called for.

I also doubt you gain any appreciable performance by splitting the code into two blocks. At least, I'd advice you to thoroughly benchmark it before duplicating code; premature optimization is the root of all evil, and all that.

As for the logic, it seems you're only interested in `'get'`, `'set'` and `'init'` values (I'll call these "the three magic values" in the following), and you call `raise()` for certain combinations of those. Anything else passes through.

So first, I would move the checking of `kind` outside the loop, since you can skip *everything* in your code, if `kind` isn't one of the three magic values.

Now, if the idea is that `kind` is guaranteed to *always* be one of the three magic values, then you can obviously skip that check. But then there's no reason to check its value; you only have to check the `other.kind` value. So either way, you can skip a bunch of code.

Your code is written to check for `kind`/`otherKind`-combinations that'll call `raise()`, but since that's most combinations, it'd be simpler to turn it inside out, and focus on the combinations that *won't* call `raise()`.

As far as I can tell, the only configurations that *won't* call `raise()` (besides a `key.name` mismatch) are:

1. if `kind` is *not* any of the three magic values
2. if `other.kind` is *not* any of the three magic values
3. if

   - `sawGetSet` is true, and
   - `kind` is `'init'`, and
   - `other.kind` is also `'init'`

*Everything else* will call `raise()`.

So those 3 configurations are the only ones we need to check, and if any of them come up true, we can just skip everything else. If none come up true, call `raise()`.

So from what I can gather, this should have the same result

```
var i, l,
    kindIsInit, kindIsMagic,
    other, otherIsInit, otherIsMagic;

// we'll be using this more than once
kindIsInit = (kind == 'init');

// Check for configuration #1
kindIsMagic = kindIsInit || (kind === 'get') || (kind === 'set');
if(!kindIsMagic) {
  // I imagine a `continue`, `break` or `return` could go here;
  // I've just put `return` as an example.
  return;
}

for(i = 0, l = node.properties.length; i < l; ++i) {
  other = node.properties[i];
  if(other.key.name !== prop.key.name) {
    continue;
  }

  // we might be using this more than once, too
  otherIsInit = (other.kind === 'init');

  // Check for configuration #3
  // (I'm checking this before #2 because it's probably infinitesimally
  // faster, but, really, the order of 2 & 3 really doesn't matter)
  if(sawGetSet && kindIsInit && otherIsInit) {
    continue;
  }

  // Check for configuration #2
  otherIsMagic = otherIsInit || (other.kind === 'get') || (other.kind === 'set');
  if(!otherIsMagic) {
    continue;
  }

  // If we're here, both kind and other.kind are one of the three "magic"
  // values, and any remaining combination of them should call raise()
  raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
}
```

That should be both faster and simpler than what you have. "Simpler" is of course relative, and you should still copiously document all this, since it'll be tricky to read regardless.

---

For fun, here's a *probably* slower (haven't tried it), but more readable (I think) version

```
// helper function
function parseKind(kind) {
  var isInit = (kind == 'init');
  return {
    init: isInit,
    magic: isInit || (kind === 'get') || (kind === 'set')
  };
}

var i, l, other, kind = parseKind(prop.kind); // I'm guessing `kind` in your code is a shortcut for `prop.kind`.

// Config #1
if(!kind.magic) { return; }

for( i = 0, l = node.properties.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
  if(node.properties[i].key.name !== prop.key.name) { continue; }

  other = parseKind(node.properties[i].kind);

  // Config #2
  if(!other.magic) { continue; }

  // Config #3
  if(sawGetSet && kind.init && other.init) { continue; }

  raise(prop.key.start, "Redefinition of property");
}
```

Comment: I'm going to include the full method call (This code is from a personal fork of the Acorn parser that I named Flying Squirrel...both can be found on GitHub). Could you take a more detailed look at it?

Comment: Also, there are several variables in the code declared outside the function as globals.

Comment: @impinball Please don't add a ton of code to your question after people (me, in this case) have answered. I spent some time writing up my answer based on the code you originally posted. As far as I can tell, I've provided a valid alternative to _that_ code, and it looks like it's still valid. But I have no idea if you actually found it useful or not. Instead, you've just asked me to review more code. And it sounds like it's code that's not written by you, which makes it off-topic for Code Review.